# Incorporating ICU as static libs into sqlite.dll

Tags: c++, windows, macos, sqlite, icu

I would like to incorporate ICU as static libs into sqlite.dll. Are there any tips on how to do this? I would like to end up with a single sqlite.dll with SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU but no further dependencies. Target platform is Windows and OSX. Please help!

It is also not out of the question to incorporate the code directly into the project, but this might be more tedious? Not sure.

Comment: I know you saw some of the other posts on this subject. How far have you gotten?

Comment: Not too far yet. I'm trying to see if I can do things in a consistent way across Windows, OSX and iOS by always compiling in static libs for icu into sqlite. In Windows generating the static libs seems non-trivial. Maybe I'm setting my hopes too much on cross-platform goodness.

Comment: @egrunin Incidentally, were you able to get your app deployed by Apple using your methods?

Comment: @egrunin any insight on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118273/using-only-utf8-encoding-in-sqlite-what-can-i-trim-out-of-the-icu-dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prebuilt libraries are available [here](http://site.icu-project.org/download/48#ICU4C-Download) for these platforms:

```
AIX 7.1 (PowerPC 64-bit) VisualAge 11.1
HP-UX 11iv3 (Itanium 64-bit)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (x86 32-bit) gcc 4.4.4
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (x86 64-bit) gcc 4.4.4
Solaris 10 (Sparc 64-bit) Forte 12
Windows (x86 32-bit) Visual Studio 10
Windows (x86 64-bit) Visual Studio 10
```

Building for OSX isn't hard, it's iOS that's tricky.

Just fyi: Apple didn't complain about the ICU module.